# How to get changes to files last build in Jenkins and send via email

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

How to get diff of commit in changed files last build in Jenkins and send via email?
On the project is used Bitbucket Mercurial.
I use the "Email-ext plugin" but can only send the path of the modified files. 
[image: Example mail]

But I need to get diff of commit.
I think I need a script to get the latest changes?
Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use Jenkins api to get the required data https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API.Use grrovy script to store the files in text format.Use email plugin to send it as inline content in email.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is more clear in what direction to move.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Last Changes plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Last+Changes+Plugin) to generate the diff and store in a file on the workspace and finally use emailext to send the diff as an attachment, following is an example using declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/last-changes-plugin'
            }
        }
        stage("send diff") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def publisher = LastChanges.getLastChangesPublisher null, "SIDE", "LINE", true, true, "", "", "", "", ""
                    publisher.publishLastChanges()
                    def changes = publisher.getLastChanges()
                    def diff = changes.getDiff()
                    writeFile file: 'build.diff', text: diff
                    emailext (
                      subject: "Sending diff of Job '${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'",
                      attachmentsPattern: '**/*.diff',
                      mimeType: 'text/html',
                      body: """<p>See attached diff of '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'.:</p>
                        <p>Check rich diff at <a href="${env.BUILD_URL}/last-changes">${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a></p>""",
                      to: "YOUR-EMAIL@XYZ.com"
                    )

               }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The generated diff can be viewd on https://diffy.org/ or any tool that can read diffs.

You can also send the diff in **html format**, see sample pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('send html diff') {
            steps {
                git 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/last-changes-plugin.git'
                script {
                  def publisher = LastChanges.getLastChangesPublisher "PREVIOUS_REVISION", "SIDE", "LINE", true, true, "", "", "", "", ""
                  publisher.publishLastChanges()
                  def htmlDiff = publisher.getHtmlDiff()
                  writeFile file: 'build-diff.html', text: htmlDiff
                    emailext (
                      subject: "Jenkins - changes of ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}",
                      attachmentsPattern: '**/*build-diff.html',
                      mimeType: 'text/html',
                      body: """<p>See attached diff of build <b>${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</b>.</p>
                        <p>Check build changes on Jenkins <b><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}/last-changes">here</a></b>.</p>""",
                      to: "YOUR-EMAIL@XYZ.com" )
                } //end script
            }
        }
    }
}
```